# Trigger an event on click or when enter key is pressed [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code and only the click event is working, but key event doesn't. Can anyone explain to me why?

```js
Btn_List.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {

 var key = e.keyCode();

 if (key === 13) {

  function OnKeyEnterPressDoThis() {
   Input_Tarea();
   showTheNmbrOfListElmts();
   orderAlphaFukkabossList();
  }

 }

});

// Agregar Tarea
Btn_List.addEventListener("click", function() {
 Input_Tarea();
 showTheNmbrOfListElmts();
 orderAlphaFukkabossList();
});
```

Comment: o my... god deam works XD:  writted.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){

            var key = e.keyCode;

            if (key === 13) {
              
              Input_Tarea(); showTheNmbrOfListElmts(); AlphabeticOrderInTheList();
                            
                            }
         
                                                            }, false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling `OnKeyEnterPressDoThis` inside the keypress event listener, you're declaring the function. Move the function out of the event listener and call it when the event is called.

Also use `e.keyCode` instead of `e.keyCode();` since `keyCode` it's not a function.

In some browsers `e.keyCode` is undefined, you have to use `e.which` in those cases.

So something like this should add a little of browser support:

```
var key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
```

**Code:**

```
function OnKeyEnterPressDoThis() {
    Input_Tarea();
    showTheNmbrOfListElmts();
    orderAlphaFukkabossList();
}

Btn_List.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {

    var key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;

    if (key === 13) {
        OnKeyEnterPressDoThis();
    }

});

// Agregar Tarea
Btn_List.addEventListener("click", OnKeyEnterPressDoThis);
```

Comment: Thanks bro it really help me

Comment: im sorry , but the page doesnt give yet the function to vote up to anyone answer , it says something like the 15 points at least of reputation , to do that , but really thanks your code was exellent ,, i really helps me

Answer (score 1):

try `e.which`

```
 Btn_List.addEventListener("keypress" , function(e){ 
    var key = e.which;
                   alert(key)
 });
 Btn_List.addEventListener("click" , function(e){ 
      alert('ff') 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should scan for `e.which`, since some browsers don't honor `e.keyCode`
2. You should use `e.preventDefault()` because an enter on a button triggers a *click* event (for accessibility reasons)
3. You should avoid using `keypress` and instead use the `keydown` or `keyup` events in order to avoid double-events (as mentioned in #2 above)

```js
var Btn_List = document.querySelector('button');

Btn_List.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

  var key = e.which && e.which || e.keyCode();

  if (key !== 9)
    e.preventDefault(); // allow tab

  if (key === 13) {
    console.log('Enter pressed');
    (function OnKeyEnterPressDoThis() {
      Input_Tarea();
      showTheNmbrOfListElmts();
      orderAlphaFukkabossList();
    }());
  }

});

// Agregar Tarea
Btn_List.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.type);
  Input_Tarea();
  showTheNmbrOfListElmts();
  orderAlphaFukkabossList();
});

function Input_Tarea() {
  console.log('Input_Tarea');
}

function showTheNmbrOfListElmts() {
  console.log('showTheNumbrOfListElmts');
}

function orderAlphaFukkabossList() {
  console.log('orderAlphaFukkabossList');
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<button onClick="console.clear()">clear console</button>
```

Comment: deam , i find for that information and my partneers never say ma that , soo thanks bro! ;)